# What color names can I use for tcolorbox?

Tags: latex

I am trying to use the `tcolorbox` package to create colored boxes with Latex. However, I am not sure what colors I can use. I looked in the [documentation](https://ctan.org/topic/colour) at `xcolor` and `latexcolors`, but these do not seem to compatible with `tcolorbox`. I tried for example

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=LimeGreen, grow to left by=-10mm]
   Example
\end{tcolorbox}
```

and got an error

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `LimeGreen'.
```

Although `LimeGreen` seems to be defined in `xcolor`.

So what colors and color names can I use for `tcolorbox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You should set `dvipsnames` as option for the `xcolor` package.

You have to properly set the `xcolor` package:

> There are also sets of color names that may be loaded by xcolor via package
> options, available in two variants: a ‘normal’ version (e.g., `dvipsnames`) and a ‘starred’ version (e.g., `dvipsnames`*)

See [here](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf#page=19) for more details.

The followig code works:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=LimeGreen, grow to left by=-10mm]
   Example
\end{tcolorbox}  


\end{document}
```